# Array in Fortran format

Tags: arrays, fortran

I have below code:

```
program test_random_seed
  implicit none
  real*16:: n , j
  real, Dimension(1,10) :: i

  i = [1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9 , 10]
  
  write(*,101) i
    pause
101 format(F0.5)    
    end program test_random_seed
```

I got this error message:

```
error 6366: The shapes of the array expressions do not conform. [I]
```

How can I correct it?

Comment: Welcome. Please read [ask]. You need to explain what is wrong with your code. Are there any error messages? Are the results wrong? Please describe what is the code supposed to do and your problem.

Comment: BTW, do not use `pause`, it is a deleted Fortran feature without a clear meaning. If you want to wait for pressing Enter, you can use `read *,`.

Comment: error 6366: The shapes of the array expressions do not conform. [I]

Comment: Use [edit] to edit important information into the question. Do not use comments.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this code? You've declared `i` to be a rank-2 array and assigning to it a rank-1 array. You need these to match - but why have you chosen `i` to be rank-2 but with extent just 1 in one dimension?

Comment: Dear francescalus, do you know what is RANDOM_SEED syntax?

Comment: `Dimension(1,10)` isn't what you think. It is **not** like VB `Dim i(1 to 10)`. It declares a 2D array akin to `Dim i(1 to 1, 1 to 10)`.

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning a 1D array literal to 2D 1x10 array.

You can fix it, by slicing the array and assigning to a subarray:

```
real, Dimension(1,10) :: i

i(1,:) = [1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9 , 10]
```

Or you can declare the array as a 1D array:

```
real, Dimension(10) :: i

i = [1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9 , 10]
```

The solution to choose depends on your ultimate goal.

We have several other questions with the same error message, but a slightly different error that caused it:
[Fortran Error # 6366: The shapes of the array expressions do not conform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19459930/fortran-error-6366-the-shapes-of-the-array-expressions-do-not-conform)
["Error: The shapes of the array expressions do not conform"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9456016/error-the-shapes-of-the-array-expressions-do-not-conform?rq=1)

The main issue is the same, the array shapes (number of elements in each dimension and the number of dimensions) must agree.

Comment: Well, I do not know what is the ultimate intention.

Comment: Dear Vladimir, do you know what is RANDOM_SEED syntax?

Comment: @nimasahakie I do, but this is not the place to write about that. We have many questions  and answers that explain it. I would suggest starting with empty `call ranom_seed()` or with `call random_init(.false., .true.)` instead. If you have some actual problem, please open a new question and show your code there.